# CSS set width of first element based on width of second element

Tags: css

I'm not sure exactly how to work what I'm trying to accomplish so bear with me...

I'm trying to set the width of an element, based on the width of a proceeding element.  visually it would look like this:

```
 container element
 --------------------------------------------
 |                         |                |
 |                         |                |
 |<--auto width for div1-->|<--div2 200px-->|
 |                         |                |
 |                         |                |
 --------------------------------------------
```

So, essentially, div2 is set to float on the right of the page, and div1 should span up to the right edge of div2 automatically

I've started a fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/yUvJs/

Any help would be greatly appreciated... thanks in advance...

Comment: Why not have div2 inside div1. Span div1 100% and give it the padding-right similar to the width of div2. Is there an essential reason to set it up the way you try.
http://jsfiddle.net/yUvJs/4/

Comment: I'm not sure where the answer suggesting using the css3 calc() method went but it just blew my mind! please repost it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use tables. Get rid of the `float`, set the two box divs to `display:table-cell` and the container div to `display:table`. The first box should then adjust its width automatically based on the width of the second box.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zCX2c/1/)

Comment: This seems to meet OP's needs exactly. Good thinking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`calc()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation) function which is new in CSS 3, to allow the first `<div>` span 100% width of its containing block *minus* the 200px of the second `<div>` - just remember to account for the 2px of border on each child element:

```
#box1 {  
display:inline-block;  
border:1px dashed blue; 
height:100%; 
opacity:.8; 
background:#ccc; 
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 204px);
width: -moz-calc(100% - 204px);
width: calc(100% - 204px); /* 2px + 2px dotted border */
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yUvJs/1/)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems to require one to provide the width of the subsequent element (div2) statically. The OP seems to want to be able to change the width of div1 based on the width of div2 dynamically.

Comment: `"I'm not sure where the answer suggesting using the css3 calc() method went but it just blew my mind! please repost it"` - Reposted

Comment: That is cool, for the OP @sadmicrowave tho will you have to worry about IE8? http://dochub.io/#css/calc

Comment: Nice, out of the box thinking!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest implementing this in JavaScript. You would do something like this in JavaScript:

```
var cont = document.getElementById("container");
var box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
var box1Width = cont.offsetWidth - box2.offsetWidth;
document.getElementById("box1").style.width = box1Width + "px" ;
```

I implemented this on your fiddle with a couple minor changes to demonstrate that it works. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/yUvJs/26/

Comment: I'm sorry but I would like to implement this with CSS

Comment: This is how I would do it, for the CSS3 calc you won't be able to support IE8 http://dochub.io/#css/calc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of all your requirements, but if you can reverse the html order:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div class='box' id='box2'></div>
    <div class='box' id='box1'></div>
</div>
```

And remove the `display: inline-block` (which should not be needed when floating), but apply a `overflow: hidden` ([and its magic](http://web.archive.org/web/20150618153020/http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/?)) to the `box1` then you get what you want as seen in **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yUvJs/32/)**.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but for the above case, can use flex:

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <!-- If you want to give id/class is up to you, css selectors can do it pretty well too for generalization purposes -->
    <div>...data...</div>
    <div>...data...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    display:flex; flex-direction:row;
    width:700px; border:1px solid black; height:300px;
}
#container > div:nth-child(1){
    flex:auto;
    border:1px dashed blue; height:100%; opacity:.8; background:#ccc;
}
#container > div:nth-child(2){
    flex:initial;
    border:1px dashed red; width:200px; height:100%; opacity:.8; background:#eee;
}
```

Try it, and see how display flex solves your problem much more elegant